# JTextArea won't show up unless I call append() on it

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

The following problem boggled my mind, so I came here for some help.

After experimenting I ended up with this block of code:

```
JTextArea chatPanel = null;
JScrollPane scrollPanel = null;

if(chatPanel == null)
{
    chatPanel = new JTextArea("derp");
    chatPanel.setEditable(false);
    chatPanel.setForeground(new Color(10,191,26));
    chatPanel.setOpaque(false);
    scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(chatPanel);
    scrollPanel.setOpaque(false);
    scrollPanel.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
    scrollPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
}

//## marked area ##         
scrollPanel.setBounds(9,596,435,138);
pane.add(scrollPanel);
```

The result? Nothing shows up. The text area with "derp" in it I expected is not there, just an empty scroll panel. Now, if I go to the ## marked area ## and replace it with this:

```
chatPanel.append("Hello.");
```

**the chatPanel shows up fine** in the scrollPanel, with its text being "derpHello.". Any ideas as per what's going on?

*For the record, pane is a simple container with a null layout that otherwise displays eveyrthing fine. Declaration, just for the record:*

```
Container pane = getContentPane()
pane.setLayout(null);
```

Comment: don't use null layout. try to call `invalidate` and `repaint` on container where you add `chatPanel`.

Comment: Am I missing something or you are intiating your `JTextArea` with the emtpy string?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Thanks for noticing this, it's a mistake. I'm initialising the TextArea with "derp", not "". Fixed.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov adding scrollPanel.revalidate() or scrollPanel.invalidate() or scrollPanel.repaint() or any combination of those did not work

Comment: Out of curiosity, why you using `setOpaque(false)`? Do you really intend to put the heavy burden on the Swing by doing so, or it really had a reason ? Do you actually know what this does ? Had you tried using this constructor instead, [JTextArea(initialText, rows, columns)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#JTextArea(java.lang.String,%int,%int)) ? Exactly on which thread you are starting your Swing Application ?

Comment: @GagandeepBali yes, there is reason for my setOpaque(false), this is only part of my application. I have a JLabel behind the JTextArea as background for it and I wanted it to be transparent, except the text. Do you recommend another way for that?

Also, my application runs on a single thread, no use for others.

Comment: @DimitrisSfounis : Ahha, now since the reason is known, and it is the right way, then what about Event Dispatch Thread. Swing is also a single threaded application. Are you starting your application on the EDT or not, that also might can lead to such behaviour sometimes when you start everything from main thread.

Comment: Make sure to start your application in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` and that `JFrame.setVisible(true);` is the last line you call to initiate your GUI. Have a look at my answer below to see full details.

Comment: @GagandeepBali Unfortunately I'm not starting my application on the EDT, sir. I'm building a class and just doing a MyClass mc = new MyClass() in the main(). Do you think that not running the app through EDT can lead to problems such as mine?

Comment: @DimitrisSfounis : Yeah, such problems can occur. Please do read [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), when you find time. It is full of knowledge part.

Comment: @DimitrisSfounis : First paragraph of [**Absolute Positioning**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html), might also be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no problem with the following code, I can see the "derp" in green just fine:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestTextArea {

    private void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTextArea chatPanel = null;
        JScrollPane scrollPanel = null;
        Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(null);
        if (chatPanel == null) {
            chatPanel = new JTextArea("derp");
            chatPanel.setEditable(false);
            chatPanel.setForeground(new Color(10, 191, 26));
            chatPanel.setOpaque(false);
            scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(chatPanel);
            scrollPanel.setOpaque(false);
            scrollPanel.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
            scrollPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        }

        // ## marked area ##
        scrollPanel.setBounds(9, 596, 435, 138);
        pane.add(scrollPanel);
        frame.validate();
        frame.setSize(600, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTextArea().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Now, I would really advise you to use an appropriate `LayoutManager` instead of that null layout. That would allow you to use `pack()` and `revalidate()` and have a much simpler and more maintainable code.

There must be something else that your code does not illustrate for now. Try to put an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: This is disconcerning, Guillaume. I don't think I left any of the important parts at work in my code out of this example, yet I'm unable to see the green "derp" without either appending("stuff") before I setBounds() or doing setSize(x,y) on the chatPanel before it gets used in the scrollPanel's conctructor.

I will keep looking into it.

Comment: @DimitrisSfounis Do you also see this issue with the code above?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Your code (and in extnsion the code in my main Question) runs fine. I thought it'd be a problem between JTextArea and something I use locally, but it might be something else entirely.

Sorry for using a null Layout but on my project I decided to go with absolute positioning instead of a Layout. I might change that later.

It might be a problem of me not running this through invokeLater() or misplacement of the setVisible(true);

Comment: Accepted as the most informative, helpful. My question was incorrect to begin with as it didn't demonstrate a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your JTextArea to display as you initialize it with the empty String. When you append something to it, there is effectively text inside.

Note that your JScrollPane will never try to resize your component inside (why else would it allow you to scroll?). Therefore, you will have to set a dimension on your JTextArea.

EDIT (after your code correction): I can see "derp" just fine with following code.

```
public class TextTest extends JFrame {
public TextTest () {
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    JTextArea chatPanel = null;
    JScrollPane scrollPanel = null;

    if(chatPanel == null)
    {
        chatPanel = new JTextArea("derp");
        chatPanel.setEditable(false);
        chatPanel.setForeground(new Color(10,191,26));
        chatPanel.setOpaque(false);
        scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(chatPanel);
        scrollPanel.setOpaque(false);
        scrollPanel.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        scrollPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    }

    //## marked area ##         
    scrollPanel.setBounds(9,596,435,138);
    pane.add(scrollPanel);
    setContentPane(pane);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TextTest();
}

}
```

Comment: See above, and my edit after that. It was a mistake, I initialise JTextArea with a new JTextArea("derp") call.

Hence why the derrived text after the append, when the chatPanel shows up, is "derpHello.".

Comment: Huh! Would you look at that. Part of your answer answered my problem, Timmos. I did not have a size set for the chatPanel inside the scrollPanel.

Comment: Well dude all I can say is that it does show up here. Anyway my answer was correct given your code before you edited it to correct your mistake. And you downvote me, thx. EDIT: OK the downvote is gone :)

Comment: @DimitrisSfounis you should never set size/bounds/location on any component, that is the responsibility of the LayoutManager. JScrollPane and JViewPort have their own LayoutManager which will set bounds appropriately.

Comment: @Timmos while your answer will solve temporarily his problems, it is incorrect and is not the proper way to go. Using an appropriate `LayoutManager` is the correct answer and not manually setting bounds.

Comment: His JTextArea is inside a JScrollPane, why would he have to apply a LayoutManager on a JScrollPane to get to see the JTextArea? He should use a LayoutManager to have the JScrollPane properly sized, but this won't affect the JTextArea directly.

Comment: @Timmos : GuillaumePolet is not really talking about, how you interpreted it. He is actually talking about the Layout set for the `Container pane` infact, just he went too deep to explain that thingy. Though for the rest, that downvote is still there, just someone upvoted you. I cann't upvote for a day though, my limit for today is gone :-)

Comment: @Timmos He does not need to set a LayoutManager on the JScrollPane since it already has its own (which eventually, through the JViewport will size the JTextArea). I suggest that he sets a LayoutManager on the `Container pane = getContentPane()` instead of using `null`. But even so, with a complete example, I am unable to reproduce his issues.

Comment: OK :) I just ignored the setBounds() thingy as this wasn't really the core of the problem. But of course you are absolutely right about using a LayoutManager. But that's just polishing up the sidecode of his example.

Comment: @Timmos I was not the one who downvoted you. Since you're so quick to jump to conclusions, let me take my upvote back.

Comment: @Dim That is very grateful. You were the only one who commented on my answer, I really thought it was you. Well OK then, for once I give an answer on SO and it's like I get punished lol

Comment: @Timmos You cannot. Plus, users below 125 score cannot downvote anyway.

Comment: @Timmos : I won't say your answer is wrong in any sense, given the OP's perspective, that's why I used my last vote to upvote your answer to negate the downvote. I really don't know how  much reputation one needs to see that thingy, though if you can click on the **0 next to your answer (b/w the up and down arrow)**, one can see how many upvotes and downvotes the answer has.